# Let $f_k :A \to \mathbb R$, $k \in \mathbb N$ be measurable maps Show that $\{x \in A : \text{ $\lim_{k\to \infty} f_k(x)$ exists } \}$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_k :A \to \mathbb R$, $k \in \mathbb N$ be measurable functions. Show that the set $\{x \in A : \text{ $\lim_{k\to \infty} f_k(x)$ exists } \}$ is measurable.

Is this like pointwise convergence? If $\lim_{k\to \infty} f_k(x)= f(x)$, then I feel like I somehow need to use the preimage condition here to show $\{x \in A : \text{ $\lim_{k\to \infty} f_k(x)$ exists } \}$ measurable?

Comment: Use the definition of the limit and the fact that the epsilons can be taken rational.

Comment: Working with the limit is problematic, because the number of options for the limit is not countable. However, a finite limit exists if and only if $f_k(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Write this by definition, and you will get a representation of this set as countable unions and intersections of measurable sets. After that you can also try the cases where the limit is infinite, this is even easier.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for a sequence of real numbers $(x_{n})$, the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}$
exists (including the cases $-\infty$ and $+\infty)$ iff $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}$.

For your case, define $g:A\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ and $h:A\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$
by $g(x)=\liminf_{n}f_{n}(x)=\sup_{n}\inf_{k\geq n}f_{k}(x)$ and
$h(x)=\limsup_{n}f_{n}(x)=\inf_{n}\sup_{k\geq n}f_{k}(x)$. Clearly
$g$ and $h$ are measurable.

Define $B:=\{x\in A\mid\lim_{n}f_{n}(x)\mbox{ exists}\}$, then $B=\{x\in A\mid g(x)=h(x)\}$ which is measurable. If your "exists" means "exists and is finite",
then $B=\{x\in A\mid g(x)=h(x)\}\cap\{x\in A\mid h(x)\in\mathbb{R}\}$,
which is also measurable.